Can we remove the spin-orbit->angular momentum synonym?
I created the tag spin-orbit to be able to follow post that are specifically about that. Now that that it has been associated I have a lot of simple angular-momentum posts that I do not care about. If it is too niche better associate it with spin or perturbation-theory or something more advanced. I cannot find a way to remove or redirect the synonyms.

Let me (at least temporarily) remove the synonym, but it won't fix OP's problem by itself. There are currently (December 2024) around 300 spin-orbit questions, but only around 50 are tagged spin-orbit, so the tag search is not comprehensive unless a dedicated custodian (OP?) maintains and updates the tag accordingly.

I can do that. Just to be clear, should I add the tag to old posts, wouldn't that bring the up in the feed?

@Mauricio per this post, mass edit is strongly discouraged but spread out over time is fine

@Mauricio I vaguely remember an occasion where a user developed a list of 100 or so posts that needed some simple edit, perhaps even another tag edit. Stack Exchange staff were willing to automate the process without bumping the posts. I feel like it was six or eight years ago.

The "bulk edit" might also have been a user who had many links to a personal website whose URL changed. I just spent a few minutes searching for the meta post, but without success.

@rob this one?

@KyleKanos That's the one ("and links therein," for some discussions and explanations on the network-wide meta). I guess it wasn't for retagging. I can't decide whether a bulk retagging would be appropriate, unless the synonym destroyed some information about the other tag that was originally present in the relevant posts.
